# Why can we consider $y$ as a new argument?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

From a book: solve the equation: $y'' + (2+4y^2)y'^3-2yy'^2 = 0\quad(y \neq const).$
They make a substitution $y' = z(y), y'' = zz'$. Well, I think of it as $y = z(y(x)), y'' = z(y(x))*z'(y(x))$ Then they get $zz'+(2+4y^2)z^3-2yz^2=0$ and make another substitution $u = -\frac{1}{z}$, and finally $u'+2uy+2+4y^2=0$. But $u' = (-\frac{1}{z})' = (-\frac{1}{y'})' = \frac{y''}{y'^2} = \frac{z'}{z}$ (as $z'$ is a derivative with respect to $x$), so I get $\frac{u'}{z} + ...$ What's wrong?
And in general, how to understand "consider y as a new independent variable...*, if y is a function of x?

Answer (score 1):

$$zz'+(2+4y^2)z^3-2yz^2=0$$
Divide by $z^3$:
$$\dfrac {z'}{z^2}+(2+4y^2)-2\dfrac yz=0$$
Since $z=z(y)$ is a function of the variable $y$ we have:

$$u=-\dfrac 1 z \implies u'=\dfrac {du}{dy}=\dfrac {du}{dz}\dfrac {dz}{dy}=\dfrac {z'}{z^2}$$
$$\implies u'+(2+4y^2)+2 yu=0$$

Note that
$$y''=\dfrac {dy'}{dx}=\dfrac {dz}{dx}=\dfrac {dz}{dy}\dfrac {dy}{dx}=z'z$$
Since $z=\dfrac {dy}{dx}=y'$.
It seems to me that you are mixing derivatives according to $y$ and according to $x$. The derivative of $z$, $z'$ in the DE is taken according to $y$ not $x$. But your $z'$ is taken according to the variable $x$ you are mixing both in
$$u'=\dfrac {z'}{z}$$
$$\dfrac {du}{dy}=\dfrac {dz}{dx}\dfrac 1z$$
This notation is really ambiguous. Since the prime has two different meaning. In the DE:
$$zz'+(2+4y^2)z^3-2yz^2=0$$
$z'$ is taken according to $y$ since no variable $x$ is present.
$$z\dfrac {dz}{dy}+(2+4y^2)z^3-2yz^2=0$$
And $u'$ means $u'=\dfrac {du}{dy}$ and not $u'=\dfrac {du}{dx}$ there is no variable $x$ in the DE where $u'$ is present.
$$ u'+(2+4y^2)+2 yu=0$$

---

so I get u′/z+... What's wrong?

Your $u'$ is equal to $\dfrac {du}{dx}$ so that:
$$\dfrac {u'}{z}=\dfrac {du}{dx}\dfrac 1 {z}$$
$$=\dfrac {du}{dx}\dfrac {dx}{dy}=\dfrac {du}{dy}$$
And this is $u'$ in your textbook.